# machine learning - predicting one instance at a time - lots of instances - trying not to use I/O

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit, liblinear, large-data

I have a large dataset and I'm trying to build a DAgger classifier for it.
As you know, in the training time, I need to run the initial learned classifier on training instances (predict them), one instance at a time.

Libsvm is too slow even for the initial learning.

I'm using OLL but that needs each instance to be written to a file and then run the test code on it and get the prediction, this involves many disk I/O.

I have considered working with vowpal_wabbit (yet I'm not sure if it will help with disk I/O) but I don't have the permission to install it on the cluster I'm working with.

Liblinear is too slow and again needs disk I/O I believe.
What are the other alternatives I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend trying Vowpal Wabbit (VW). If Boost (and gcc or clang) is installed on the cluster, you can simply compile VW yourself (see the [Tutorial](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial)). If Boost is not installed, you can compile it yourself as well.

VW contains more modern algorithms than [OLL](https://code.google.com/p/oll/). Moreover, it contains several structured prediction algorithms (SEARN, DAgger) and also a C++ and [Python interface](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/learning2search_python.pdf) to it. See [an iPython notebook tutorial](http://tinyurl.com/pyvwsearch).

As for the disk I/O: for one-pass learning, you can pipe the input data directly to vw (`cat data | vw`) or run `vw --daemon`. For multi-pass learning, you must use cache file (the input data in binary fast-to-load format), which takes some time to create (during the first pass, unless it already existed), but the subsequent passes are much faster because of the binary format.

Comment: Thank you! This took a long time, sorry! I didn't know VW has Python interface too. I was having problems installing both VW and OLL on the cluster as I said in the question. For now, I ended up using "oll" for python. But I definitely should look through VW interface, having ready-to-go DAgger and SEARN sounds enticing!